Sectorized antenna with azimuth (Bearing in degrees) and Lat-Long information
How to create shape to show sectorized antenna with azimuth (Bearing in degrees) and Lat-Long information. This is to represent a cellular site. Normally a cellular site is from 1 to 6 sectors depending on its use. The site has coordinates and would like to load or represents data information inside that shape.I tried and look but not successful finding one that resembles or close to a pie shape that I am looking for.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Do you want to show your "shape" on a web page or from a deskop application?

Hi, I am planning to show or use this shape from a desktop application as part of my personal app for work analysis. I am also new to python and still learning. This shape will be used on several site location to map cellular towers..
